# Apache proxy for CAS SSO - configuration example

Tags: apache-2.2, reverse-proxy, single-sign-on

I need to use an Apache (or other) proxy to enable SSO on a platform which does not natively support [CAS](http://www.jasig.org/cas) (namely [splunk](http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/Security/ConfigureSplunkSSO))

It looks like everyone on Internet has "successfully configured their Apache CAS proxy" but we (Google and I) cannot find any simple, straightforward example on how to set this up.

Would someone be willing to share a basic version of their configuration of such a proxy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally managed to do this with the configuration below. `splunk.example.com:8000` is the actual site to be accessed, `cas.example.com` is the CAS server. The proxy is on the same machine and will be defined in a `VirtualHost`.

**Apache**

The `VirtualHost` which serves the to-be-SSO-ed application (`splunk.example.com:8000`)

```
<VirtualHost splunk.example.com:80>
ServerName splunk.example.com
DocumentRoot /var/www

CASCookiePath /var/cache/apache2/mod_auth_cas/
CASLoginURL https://cas.example.com/cas/login?gateway=true
CASValidateURL  https://cas.example.com/cas/proxyValidate

<Location />
        Authtype CAS
        require valid-user
        CASAuthNHeader Cas-User
</Location>

ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass        / http://localhost:8000/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8000/
</VirtualHost>
```

**CAS**

The module to load is [`mod_auth_cas`](https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASC/mod_auth_cas). The version I had on Debian failed on some crypto module, it is enough to clone the git repository, configure, make and install and it works out of the box

Comment: @kashyap you are welcome. There seems to be a small problem with this config, though. I am investigating right now (the problem is posted at [splunkbase](http://splunk-base.splunk.com/answers/81764/sso-sometimes-fails-with-deeper-urls))